# SSL peer had some unspecified issue with the certificate it received

Tags: php, curl, openssl, centos7, nss

I have this error

> SSL peer had some unspecified issue with the certificate it received.

I'm use centos, NSS library.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, <cert_path>);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  <key_path>);                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this ->url_merchant);
```

Comment: Is this a self-signed certificate ?

Comment: No this is merchant id for bank, for card payment.

Comment: Perhaps this can help - http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html